# Solve the following system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

The differential equations are :

$$ ( n_{j,k,0} )'(x) = - \frac {jn_{j,k,0}(x)} {a-x}, $$

$$ ( n_{j,k,b} )'(x) = \frac { (j-b+1)n_{j,k,b-1}(x) - (j-b)n_{j,k,b}(x) } {a-x}, $$

for $ 0\lt b\lt c $.

$$ (f_{j,k})'(x) = \frac{ (j-c+1)n_{j,k,c-1}(x) }{a-x}.$$
Here, the second equation holds with $0\lt b\lt c$.

Comment: just want to comment that the second equation holds with all 0 less than b and b less than c.
Sorry that I donot know how to type it here.

Comment: as stated, this is unclear. For what $x,b,k,j$ do you seek the solution? Is $x$ allowed to equal $a$? are the $b$ real-valued, or assumed integers? I'm assuming the latter since you are using it as an index. If not, this looks like a functional differential equation. Also, you need additional conditions on $n$ and $f$ to specify them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. Appreciate that !

I seek the solution for $x$. $ n_{j,k,0} $, $n_{j,k,b}$ and $f_{j,k}$ are all functions with respect of $x$.

$x$ is a variable. Except $x$, all others are supposed to know.

$b$ is an integer.

Thanks again !

Comment: I will state the question again :

$$(n_{j,k,0}'(\tau))= \frac{jn_{j,k,0}(\tau)}{\lambda -\tau}.$$

$$(n_{j,k,\theta})'(\tau)=\frac{(j-\theta +1)n_{j,k,\theta -1}(\tau)-(j-\theta)n_{j,k,\theta}(\tau)}{\lambda - \tau}$$

for $(0<\theta < \Omega).$

Comment: and $$f_{j,k}'(\tau) = \frac{ (j-\Omega +1)n_{j,k,\Omega -1}(\tau) }{\lambda - \tau}.$$

with $\tau \in [0,\lambda)$, and the initial conditions:

$n_{j,k,0}=(1-\alpha)P(j,k),$ $n_{j,k,\theta}(0)=0$ for $0<\theta <\Omega$, and $f_{j,k}(0)=\alpha P(j,k).$

Comment: Here is a possible way, which i do not quite understand.

Let $u=u(\tau) = - ln(\lambda - \tau)$. Then $u(0)= -ln(\lambda)$. 
We write the system of differential equations with respect to $u$:

$$( n_{j,k,0} )'(u) = jn_{j,k,0}(u),$$
$$( n_{j,k,\theta})'(u) = (j-\theta +1)n_{j,k,\theta -1}(u)-(j-\theta)n_{j,k,\theta}(u).$$

Comment: But from what I understand, 

$$ (n_{j,k,\theta})'(u) =  \frac{d}{d\tau} (n_{j,k,\theta}) \frac{d}{du} \tau    $$

Comment: that is to say, $$ (n_{j,k,\theta}'(u)) = \frac{ (j-\theta +1)n_{j,k,\theta -1}(\tau) - (j-\theta) n_{j,k,\theta}(\tau)   }{\lambda - \tau}  e^{-u}  $$

$$= (j-\theta +1) n_{j,k,\theta -1} (\tau) - (j-\theta) n_{j,k,\theta}(\tau).$$

Comment: This is quite different from what I wrote before. And I cannot understand why.

Comment: Continue that way I saw.
Then, they use $$\frac{d}{du}(n_{j,k,\theta}(u)e^{(j-\theta -1)(u-u(0))})  = e^{ (j-\theta -1)(u-u(0))  } (j-\theta) n_{j,k,\theta} (u),$$ and by induction, can find

$$n_{j,k,\theta}(u) = e^{-(j-\theta) (u-u(0))} \sum_{r=0}^{\theta} {j-r \choose i-r} (1-e^{-(u-u(0))})^{i-r} n_{j,k,\theta}(u(0)).$$

Comment: I do not quite understand the differential equation above,
From what I understand, let $$f(u)= n_{j,k,\theta}(u).$$
$$a=j-\theta -1,$$
$$b=u(0).$$
Then, $$\frac{d}{du}(n_{j,k,\theta}(u)e^{(j-\theta -1)(u-u(0))})$$

$$= \frac{d}{du}(f(u)e^{a(u-b)})= e^{a(u-b)}(a+1)f(u).$$

Comment: The very last equation of previous comment is based on the differential equation they use.

But, the left hand side of the very last equation is
$$f'(u) e^{a(u-b)}+f(u)e^{a(u-b)}a.$$
Hence, $$f'(u)e^{a(u-b)} + f(u) e^{a(u-b)}a= e^{a(u-b)}f(u)(a+1).$$ 
That is to say,
$$ f'(u)e^{a(u-b)} = e^{a(u-b)}f(u), $$
$$f'(u)=f(u).$$
So, $$f(u)=Ce^{u}.$$
for some constant $C$.

Comment: I do not know what is wrong with my reasoning.
Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If b is an integer, you can simply solve the equations successively, starting with b=0. If b is supposed to be real, you need to explain what $n_{j,k,b-1}$ is supposed to mean for b between 0 and 1. Also, what is the point of the index k? Nothing in the equations depends on k!

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.

$b$ is an integer, I do not quite understand how to solve it successively.

index $k$ could be anything, although it really does not matter too much here. Can just assume it is fixed.

Comment: By solving successively, I mean that you first solve the equation for b=0, then you use that solution to solve for b=1, etc. At each step, you only need to solve a linear equation.